# How to replace background green color

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using lenscorrection filter on a video and the result contains green background as canvas!

How Can i replace this color with different one or an image?
This is the command i used:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -vf "lenscorrection=cx=0.5:cy=0.5:k1=0.4:k2=0.4" sss.mp4
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a byproduct of the lenscorrection algorithm, originally meant to work on RGB pixels only. If the output pixel has no corresponding input pixel mapped, it is populated with 0, but in a YUV format, that's a shade of green.

As a workaround, you'll have to force manual format conversion before and after the filter.

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -vf "format=gbrp,lenscorrection=cx=0.5:cy=0.5:k1=0.4:k2=0.4,format=yuv420p" sss.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working.


Just a question, is there a way to directly replace the black color with background image or video?  

I think i can do this through specially designed background with blend option.